# Dynamic test data set on dbunit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dbunit

I want to create a test data set of my integration test with dbunit dynamically, so let say that I  I have a class A, another class B and C where B and C has dependencies with A, and finally another class D that has another dependency with B and C.

- For test 1 I want a test data set with A and B -> where A has id 1, B id 1
- For test 2 I want a test data set with A, B and D -> where A has id 1, B id 1 and D id 1
- For test 3 I want a test data set with A, C and D -> where A has id 1, C id 1 and D id 1
- For test 4 I want a test data set with A, B, C  and D -> where A has id 1, B has id 1, C id 2 and D id 1

So how can I create this dynamic test data to use in the test 2,3 the same id for B and C and id 1, 2 for B, C in the test 4?.

any idea?

EDIT: So far I found this solution http://merereflections.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/dbunit-and-setting-up-changing-data/

Comment: So, you want 4 different data sets. What prevents you from defining them? Shameless plug: for an easier way to setup your data, you might want to try DbSetup instead: http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: too late to refactor all our integration test, we need continue using dbUnit. But thanks!, I will read it anyway